# unable to connect to aws machine : operation timed out

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and created key pair correctly

```
@air~/.ec2 - 14:25:10$ ec2-add-keypair mykey > mykey.pem
```

and run the instance with same key

```
@air~/.ec2 - 14:25:15$ec2-run-instances ami-a29243cb -k mykey -t t1.micro
```

when try to connect to machine I see

```
@air~/.ec2 - 14:25:22$ ssh  -v -i mykey.pem ec2-user@ec2-21-20-42-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-user@ec2-21-20-42-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com [21.20.42.185] port 22.
ssh: connect to host ec2-user@ec2-21-20-42-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

I have even tried `root@ec2-21-20-42-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com` but no luck

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been resolved.

**Reasons**

- The security group was default instead of what I created. fixed with command

> ec2-run-instances ami-a29243cb -k mykey -t t1.micro **-g worker**

- login as ubuntu instead of ec2-user

> ssh -v -i ~/.ec2/mykey.pem
>   ubuntu@ec2-13-24-2-39.compute-1.amazonaws.com

and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: sigh, I'm been using AWS for a few weeks now, and I completely forgot about that security group thing

Comment: Thanks, security group was the problem for me.